# Box-Ljung test giving different p-values in R and Python

Tags: python, r, p-value

I have code in R and I am translating it to Python for scalability issue to work with PySpark. I am comparing if I get the same results with R and Python. I am fitting auto ARIMA models with exogenous features. When I test the autocorrelation of the residuals using Box-Ljung, I get different  p-values but when I compare the residuals, they are very close. R considers degrees of freedom while Python does not. Which way is more appropriate?

The data can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/fissehab/fissehab.github.io/blob/master/Miscellaneous/uschange.csv). As you can see below, the degree of freedom used by R is 5 and the p-value is  0.3017. With Python, it does not use degrees of freedom and the array of the p-values is very high. If I remove the degree of freedom and perform the test with R, I get the same results (0.80958073).

**R**

```
library(forecast)
library(readr)
df = read_csv('uschange.csv')
df = as.matrix(df)
my_fit <- auto.arima(df[,"Consumption"], xreg=df[,"Income"])
checkresiduals(fit, plot = FALSE)
```

> Ljung-Box test
>    data:  Residuals from Regression with ARIMA(1,0,2) errors
>   Q* = 6.0465, df = 5, 
>   p-value = 0.3017
>   Model df: 5.   Total lags used: 10

**Python**

```
import pandas as pd
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import acorr_ljungbox
df = pd.read_csv("uschange.csv")

arima_model = auto_arima(y = df['Consumption'], 
                  exogenous = df[['Income']],
                  start_p=1, 
                  start_q=1,
                  max_p=3, 
                  max_q=3,
                  seasonal=False,
                  d = None,  
                  error_action='ignore',  
                  suppress_warnings=True, 
                  stepwise=False)
 acorr_ljungbox(arima_model.resid(), lags = 10)
```

The second array is the p-values:

> (array([0.00775255, 0.04434567, 0.37206872, 0.57959716, 0.87815042,
>           1.30443762, 1.83487883, 5.90958235, 6.05594458, 6.06726358]),
>
> array([0.92983808, 0.97807118, 0.94595004, 0.9653037 , 0.97178326,
>           0.97141244, 0.96841158, 0.6573594 , 0.73430632, 0.80958073]))